# Convert partition from MBR to GPT

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, windows, disk-utility, partition

I want to install Win10 in a partition on my Macbook Pro.

Model: Macbook Pro 13' MID 2010.

I already have Windows Software Support that I downloaded from Boot Camp app.

To do so, I created a partition with 140Gb with I called "BOOTCAMP".
I need to change this partition to GPT so, to do so, I downloaded GPT fdisk.
After I installed it I opened "terminal" and run the command `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0`

I got this:

```
    Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
NOTE: Write test failed with error number 1. It will be impossible to save
changes to this disk's partition table!
You may need to deactivate System Integrity Protection to use this program. See
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-turn-off-the-rootless-in-OS-X-El-Capitan-10-11
for more information.

Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/disk0: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Sector size (logical): 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): CCEA39AF-B83B-4EB6-93F8-9A87464AB53D
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 262157 sectors (128.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       701207815   334.2 GiB   AF00  Sem nome
   3       701207816       702477351   619.9 MiB   AB00  
   4       702477352       976510983   130.7 GiB   0700  

Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): n

Expert command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!
```

The thing is, I'm afraid the process will overwrite my main partition as well.
Right now if I go to my Disk Utility I have this:
[image]

It is in Portuguese but I think you can understand the important things.

So, my question is: If I give it a "Y" in terminal, will it overwrite both of my partitions or only the partition called "BOOTCAMP"? (Will it erase my main partition?)

Thank you

Comment: The decision whether to use a BIOS or EFI boot method for Widows 10 depends on the model/year of your Mac. You need to use a boot method compatible with the Windows Support Software (BOOTCAMP) supplied by Apple. So, edit your question and add the year of your MacBook Pro.

Comment: Additionally, I think that you can also convert the disk to GPT through your windows installation media, as described in this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-installing-using-the-mbr-or-gpt-partition-style

Comment: Does your 2010 MacBookPro have a working DVD drive?

Comment: What @Mythic Cocoa has posted is not true.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes it does

Comment: Look, I tried. If later you decide you what my help, let me know.

Comment: @DavidAnderson, I was referring to the method I had mentioned in the next comment, i.e., converting to GPT via Windows installation media. I think you might have mistaken it for gdisk instead. However, I'll still delete the comment to prevent further confusion.

Comment: @Mythic Cocoa: If João follows in instructions in the link you posted, the partition table entries for macOS will be removed from both the Master Boot Record (MBR) table and the GUID Partition Table (GPT). If  João continues and manages to start installing Windows, then the macOS files will be overwritten by the Windows files. I can not image why you would post a link to instructions that will destroy the files on his Mac.

Comment: Did you get Windows installed on your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do what you propose, then you are correct.

While using `gdisk`, you can the check GUID Partition Table (GPT) by entering the `P` command. After you enter the `N` command to change the Master Boot Record (MBR) table, you can again enter the `P` command. You will see the  GPT is unchanged. To see the changes to the MBR table, you will need to enter the following command before and after using `gdisk`.

```
sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0
```

## But, you do not want to do this for a 2010 MacBook Pro.

The 13-inch, mid 2010  MacBook Pro should install Windows 10 using the legacy BIOS boot method. The Windows Support Software for installing Windows 10 on your model Mac can be found at: [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US).

Apple does not officially support Windows on your model Mac beyond version 7. The drivers for 64 bit Windows 7 are in the [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US)  download. Fortunately, Windows 10 is designed to accept older version drivers, when current drivers are unavailable. Unfortunately, these drivers are designed for the legacy BIOS boot method.

> Note: I am used the [Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1630?locale=en_US) download to install 64 bit Windows 10 Pro on my 2007 iMac. Apple does not officially support any 64 bit versions of Windows on any 2007 Mac models. In spite of this, I am able to run 64 bit Windows 10 Pro on my 2007 iMac.

Comment: But will it erase the data I have in my main partition? That's what I'm afraid about

Comment: If you want to do what you propose, then you are correct. The data on the main partition will not be erased.

Comment: You might want to add as to why this should not be done on a 2010 Macbook Pro. Also, I believe you should change "what" to "want" :)

Comment: @Mythic Cocoa: Thanks for the suggestion. Also, if you see a mistake, feel free to edit my answer. This is better than posting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **Hybrid MBR** which is both MBR and GPT at the same time and disk partition information is mirrored in both GPT and MBR - see [Hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html). So OS that looks for GPT will find GPT info and OS that looks for MBR will see that. Disk utility and Boot Camp Assistant will make sure that the changes in GPT table will be reflected in a MBR copy. So in effect the **BOOTCAMP** partition you have created is already in the GPT table (as well as in MBR) and your proposed changes are not needed. Even your output from gdisk shows:

```
Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, yes it will overwrite both partitions, as it will overwrite the partition table.

Comment: Oh, glad I didn't give it a go then! So how can I overwrite only "BOOTCAMP" partition?

Comment: gdisk does not overwrite any partitions! What gdisk does is write values to the Master Boot Record (MBR) table and the GUID Partition Table (GPT).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Oh! :P